# Auth MySQL with blowfish Encryption

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, webdav, virtualhost

I've my usernames and passwords stored in a mysql db with blowfish encrption.
In php I can encrypt the password like this:

```
crypt($pwd, _SALT_)
```

where `$pwd = 'userpwd'` and `_SALT_ = $2a$07...`

I'm looking for a way to use the user-table also in a VirtualHost with `mod_auth_mysql`. I know it's possible with md5 using `Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5` but I'd rather stay with blowfish.

How do I tell mysql_auth to use blowfish? And where do I enter the salt?

**EDIT:**

Basic problem here is that I have to use a '_' between the key words in the vhost file. So it looks like:

```
<Location /webdav>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "jst-development"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
Auth_MySQL on
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative on
Auth_MySQL_DB user
Auth_MySQL_User user
...
```

instead of [taken from http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE]

```
AuthMySQLDB authdata
AuthMySQLUserTable user_info
AuthMySQLGroupField user_group
```

to stop apache complaining about the syntax. can someone tell me why or tell me the '_'-syntax for `AuthMySQLSaltField <>`

//**EDIT 2:**
Version: libapache2-mod-auth-mysql (4.3.9-13ubuntu1)

//**EDIT 3:**
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Exact error when using the 'official syntax' without '_':
Invalid command 'AuthMySQLDB', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Since apache is complaining... Which exact version of apache you have? And maybe what is the exact error you get (paste)?

Comment: "Invalid command 'AuthMySQLDB', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"



Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
AuthMySQLPwEncryption crypt
```

http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE

> ```
> AuthMySQLPwEncryption none | crypt | scrambled | md5 | aes | sha1
>   The encryption type used for the passwords in AuthMySQLPasswordField:
>     none: not encrypted (plain text)
>     crypt: UNIX crypt() encryption
>     scrambled: MySQL PASSWORD encryption
>     md5: MD5 hashing
>     aes: Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption
>     sha1: Secure Hash Algorihm (SHA1)
>
>   WARNING: When using aes encryption, the password field MUST be a BLOB type
>   (i.e.  TINYBLOB).  MySQL will strip trailing x'20' characters (blanks), EVEN
>   IF THE COLUMN TYPE IS BINARY!
>
> AuthMySQLSaltField <> | <string> | mysql_column_name
>
>   Contains information on the salt field to be used for crypt and aes
>   encryption methods.  It can contain one of the following:
>     <>: password itself is the salt field (use with crypt() only)
>     <string>: "string" as the salt field
>     mysql_column_name: the salt is take from the mysql_column_name field in the
>       same row as the password
>
>   This field is required for aes encryption, optional for crypt encryption.
>   It is ignored for all other encryption types.
> ```

Comment: well, the thing is, that apache complains about the syntax, so I had to use (Auth_MySQL on; Auth_MySQL_Authoritative on;...) [using '_']. So AuthMySQLSaltField isn't working. I also tried Auth_MySQL_SaltField; Auth_MySQL_Salt_Field,...

Answer (score 0):

modauthmysql seems to not have seen any Developer love for over 7 years. My current guess on your problem is some incompatibility problems this causes with apache 2.2 that you are using.

After looking a bit around on how I would solve the same problem I came across this documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html

This seems to be able to do what you want, provided you configure it right with all its options.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't figure it out: Where do I have to tell (the SQL-Statement?) to encrypt the incoming pasword with blowfish (enter my $2$... salt)

Comment: Sorry, I dug more into this on both Apache and Mysql side. Blowfish is a no go. DES and AES or the standard CRYPT are available in one or another form, and of course SHA1 and MD5 hashing, but blowfish seems to be unused by these systems. I have not looked into it by detail yet, but maybe one of the other auth modules in apache would allow you to specify a system call (script) that could do the trick for you?

Comment: It's just interesting that there is a solution with "the other" syntax. I still didn't figure out the difference of the syntax, if they are depending on the lib version or the apache2 version

Comment: IMHO I agree, there is an incompatibility problem in there somewhere. Though in your case I would drop blowfish and use a salted SHA1. You don't want those passwords encrypted anyways, they can still be retrieved which can't really be in your best interest either.

Comment: I'm using https anyway, so there should be no problem. it's just that i would like use an existing user table, where The passwords are stored in an blowfish encrypted way..

Comment: If they are truly encrypted, you could easy decrypt and hash them from that. No hassle on the frontend unless you have somewhere that relies on being allowed to see the passwords plaintext (password recovery mails, using it on different platforms, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Look for the directive in /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-auth-mysql/DIRECTIVES.gz

Path should be specific to your system, the one above is for Debian Lenny